# Java - Force implementation of an implemented method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, structure, abstract

I have three classes which I have a problem with. They are named: GameScene, StageScene, StageOne. My problem is that I want to implement initialize in StageScene, but still force StageOne to implement it, so that whenever someone uses a StageOne object (stageOne.initialize()), initialize would be run for both StageScene and StageOne. Anyone know how this could be done?

```
public abstract class GameScene 
{
    public abstract void initialize();
}

public abstract class StageScene extends GameScene
{
    public abstract void initialize()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
public class StageOne extends StageScene
{
    public void initialize()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this question helped me think about a design problem I'm handling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it with a wrapper:

```
public abstract class StageScene extends GameScene
{
    final public void initialize()
    {
        //your initialization
        subInitialize();
    }

    protected abstract void subInitialize();
}
```

And in the child class:

```
public class StageOne extends StageScene
{
    public void subInitialize()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: @assylias - sure. made minimal changes to the original code, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You could break it into two separate methods

```
public abstract class GameScene 
{
    public abstract void initializeScene();
    public abstract void initializeStage();
}

public abstract class StageScene extends GameScene
{
    public void initializeScene()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
public class StageOne extends StageScene
{
    public void initializeStage()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```